# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feedparser'

Tags: python, module, feedparser

I have Python 3.11 and I have done everything expect Anaconda thing in this video below to try and fix this issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvbUqf3Tb1s&t=181s&ab_channel=TechWithTim

Here is the error:

> C:\Python311\python.exe
> C:\Users\16789\PycharmProjects\cyberNewsfeed\main.py  Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\16789\PycharmProjects\cyberNewsfeed\main.py", line 1, in
>
> import feedparser ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feedparser'

Attached is a screenshot of my interpeter and structue.

Tried everything in the linked video besides anaconda and i was expecting it to run. I restarted my computer as well.

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install the feedparser module.

Comment: I also have venu enabled in source folders because that is where my python and feedparser is

Comment: pip install feedparser

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. pip installed the module for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python to run the code.  Show us the output of this command `pip --version` and also of running this code `import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the missing package. Try this in a shell inside your python environment.

```
pip install feedparser
```

Comment: Install where? already have it installed in Python311

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: feedparser in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (6.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: sgmllib3k in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from feedparser) (1.0.0)

Comment: inside your python environment. If you used a virtualenv, then install there. If you installed to your system python environment (I assume this is Python311 in your case) then assure that you are running the correct binary. You may have installed the package to a different python installation (Anaconda?)